# CSS border-image not working

Tags: html, css

I am currently trying to use CSS's border-image to apply a custom border to a div.  I feel like I have all the right code, but my image isn't being displayed as the border.  Could someone take a look at this html/css code and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="box">
&nbsp;
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
   body { text-Align: center; } /* CENTER ALIGN FOR IE */

#PC_Attack_Lightbox {

  /*** CENTER ALIGN BOX ***/
  text-Align: left;
  margin: 0 auto;

  /*** SET WIDTH & HEIGHT ***/
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;

  background: #EBF5FF; /* SET BG */

  /*** APPLY BORDER-IMAGE ***/
    border:35px outset brown;
    -moz-border-image:url(img/wood2.jpg) 25 30 10 20 repeat;
    -webkit-border-image:url(img/wood2.jpg) 25 30 10 20 repeat;
    border-image:url(img/wood2.jpg) 25 30 10 20 repeat;
}
```

Comment: Alright, I'm not understanding this (I blame a brain fart).  It looks to me as though I have the ID and css selector the same.

Comment: your border-images in style `#PC_Attack_Lightbox` so map your div to   `div id="PC_Attack_Lightbox"`.

Answer (score 0):

because you use box div and your write css on #PC_Attack_Lightbox
so use PC_Attack_Lightbox

```
<div id="PC_Attack_Lightbox">
&nbsp;
</div>​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="PC_Attack_Lightbox">

// your code here

</div>

body { text-Align: center; } /* CENTER ALIGN FOR IE */

#PC_Attack_Lightbox {

  /*** CENTER ALIGN BOX ***/
  text-Align: left;
  margin: 0 auto;

  /*** SET WIDTH & HEIGHT ***/
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;

  background: #EBF5FF; /* SET BG */

  /*** APPLY BORDER-IMAGE ***/
    border:35px outset brown;
    -moz-border-image:url(img/wood2.jpg) 25 30 10 20 repeat;
    -webkit-border-image:url(img/wood2.jpg) 25 30 10 20 repeat;
    border-image:url(img/wood2.jpg) 25 30 10 20 repeat;
}
```